# the sum of values of a second column of a file

Tags: python

I have a txt file containing on each line 2 values separated by a space:

```
x1 y1
x2 y2
x3 y3
...
xn yn
```

I want to get another file containing:

```
x1 y1
x2 y1+y2
x3 y1+y2+y3
...
xn y1+y2+y3+...+yn
```

What is the quickest (I mean easiest) way to do this in python ?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)? It is always a good start to actually try and code something.

Comment: From your specs, it is not clear if you want the sum in the 2nd column, or the lines with the individual values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will get you *started*.

Given `data.txt`:

```
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
```

and this code snippet:

```
with open('data.txt') as inf:
    ysum = 0
    for line in inf:
        line = line.split()
        x, y = [float(i) for i in line]
        ysum += y
        print x, ysum
```

will give you (using `float()` above):

```
1.0 1.0
2.0 3.0
3.0 6.0
4.0 10.0
```

On the other hand, if you wanted the lines with the `+`:

```
with open('data.txt') as inf:
    yline = []
    for line in inf:
        line = line.split()
        x = int(line[0])
        yline = '+'.join(yline + [(line[1])])
        print x, yline
        yline = [yline]
```

will give you (using `int()` this time):

```
1 1
2 1+2
3 1+2+3
4 1+2+3+4
```

I suspect the above code, esp the 2nd one, could probably be streamlined/optimized more, but should be sufficient to get you started.

You still will have adjust the conversion from string to appropriate type (`float` or `int`) and also create the output file and write to it in the format you prefer. These are details you can best decide.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way code-wise is [`numpy.cumsum()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html#numpy.cumsum) if you already use `numpy` arrays:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.loadtxt("input.txt")
a[:,1].cumsum(out=a[:,1]) # accumulate values in the 2nd column
np.savetxt("output.txt", a) #note: you could specify fmt="%d" for integer array
```

Comment: I always write `a[:,1] = np.cumsum(a[:,1])` rather than using the method and `out`, which I'd actually forgotten existed, but this was my first thought.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('input.txt') as inf, open('output.txt','w') as outf:
    datatype = int    # or float
    yy = 0
    for line in inf:
        x,y = line.split()
        yy += datatype(y)
        outf.write('{} {}'.format(x, yy))
```

Answer (score 0):

**data.txt:**

```
1 10
2 20
3 30
4 40
```

**code:**

```
with open('data.txt') as f1,open('output.txt','w') as f2:
    lis=[map(int,line.split()) for line in f1]
    for i,z in enumerate(lis):
        f2.write("{0:d} {1:d}\n".format(z[0],sum(lis[j][1] for j in range(i+1))))
```

**output**:

```
1 10
2 30
3 60
4 100
```